# how to change a parent id of child and subchilds in hierarchyid

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, hierarchyid

```
id       hierid
---------------------
2   |    /2/
7   |    /2/7/
8   |    /2/8/
11  |    /2/7/11/
13  |    /2/8/13/
17  |    /2/8/17/
37  |    /2/8/37/
```

i want to change the root of this to /3/ that means the output i want to get is

```
id     hierid
---------------------
2   | /3/
7   | /3/7/
8   | /3/8/
11  | /3/7/11/
13  | /3/8/13/
17  | /3/8/17/
37  | /3/8/37/
```

like this how can i do it using hierarchyid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE  mytable
SET     hierid = hierid.GetReparentedValue('/2/', '/3/')
WHERE   hierid.IsDescendantOf('/2/') = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
UPDATE tbl SET hierid = REPLACE(hierid, '/2/', '/3/');
```

Comment: UPDATE tbl SET hierid = REPLACE(hierid.ToString(), '/2/', '/3/')

Comment: because it is hierarchyid so want to convert to string using ToString()